# Why is there no Site Stats block in sidebar in Home Improvement?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

On other SE sites there is a Site Stats block in the right hand sidebar showing stats for questions, answers, users etc... There isn't one on Home Improvement - why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those stats only appear for public beta.

Comment: OK, that explains it. Why is that out of interest? I'm always interested to see how the site is growing, even if it is in private beta...

Answer (score 1):

This site is still in private beta, and there seem to be some subtle differences between a public beta site and a private beta site.  See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58164/) I asked on meta SO earlier for one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can see those stats in Area 51: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/170/home-improvement